# what is the better way to get the information from this website with scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape this [website](https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/bodegas/arriendo/) with scrapy and I have had to search for each link extracting the information from each one, I would like to know if there is an API of the site that I can use (I don't know how to find it).

I would also like to know how I can obtain the latitude and longitude? Currently the map is shown but I do not know how to obtain the numbers

I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation, and is not a way to have design, coding or research work done for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website may be loading the data dynamically using Javascript. Use your browser dev tools and look at the networking tab, look for any XHR calls which may be accessing an API. Then you can scrape from that directly.